# How can I use an if statement to turn autofilter off if it is already on otherwise leave off

Tags: vba, excel

I want a bit of code that turns autofilter off if it is currently turned on. I can't seem to get it working and haven't found a solution.

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: You want to remove the filter entirely, or reset it such that all columns are set to 'All'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is something that I use. It works with a hard-coded range, but you can pass it as a parameter as well. Pretty much, if there is autofilter , it will disable it on `A2:K2`.

```
Public Sub CleanTheFilters()

    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("A2:K2").AutoFilter
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome,        @RobBlagg